# C# How do I make my loop not loop back to the first line?

Tags: c#

I have been working on a text adventure for a while, but I am having an issue. I have a tutorial, but I want to know how when the user types something that isn't listed, instead of asking the question again, just displaying the option. My example here is a tutorial option that isn't available yet, so they have to type back. I want it so if they type anything other then back, it just displays [Back] and not "That option isn't listed.". In the code example I have tried to use more than one static void because maybe I couldn't reference my own void but that wouldn't work, And I separated the writing and the back option into two but it still doesn't work. When the code example has SW(60, "text") that is just a custom thing for slow write and the 60 is 60 millisecond delay. So, whenever I run it, and type something other then back it will say "That option isn't listed.", like planed but then somehow clear the line and tell you the settings are disabled.
Here is my code.

'''
static string TutorialBack;

```
    public static void TutorialLine()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        SW(40, "The tutorial is currently being devolped, thank you for your patience and support.");
        Game.TutorialOof();
    }
    public static void TutorialOof()
    {
        Game.Tutorial();
    }

    static void Tutorial()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1600);
        Console.WriteLine();
        SW(40, "[Back]");
        Console.WriteLine();
        TutorialBack = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.Equals(TutorialBack, "back", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Game.Menue();
        }
        else
        {
            SW(60, "That option isn't listed.");
            Game.TutorialOof();
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In your own words, what is the purpose of the `TutorialOof` method?

Comment: It was actually just to see if the reason that it was not working was because I cannot go to the static void I already am in.

Comment: What book, web site etc. are you using to learn programming with?

Comment: Well I started with a text adventure tutorial, but over time I decided to learn by myself and google when I have an issue. So mainly self taught - except for the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Text adventures are still alive? ;)

I think you should use the `var` to check equals not the `type` (string).

```
// ...
if (TutorialBack.Equals("Back", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
   Console.Clear();
   Game.Menue();
}
// ...
```

Edit: Sorry if I misunderstood what you mean. If you want keep the current just quote out the instruction inside else.

```
else
{
   //SW(60, "That option isn't listed.");
   //Game.TutorialOof();
}
```

Or

```
else
{
   //SW(60, "That option isn't listed.");
   Game.TutorialOof();
}
```